# MongoDB Compass add year to date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I try to insert a new document with this code:

```
{
    "date": {
        $dateAdd: {
            startDate: "$currentDate",
            unit: "year",
            amount: 1
        }
    }
}
```

"date" should be the current date + 1 year. However I get an error message that the document contains an error.

How do I fix the error and insert the document?

Comment: "Contains an error" is not very smart - what is the error you get? Please provide the entire command.

Comment: That is the error message. There is no further information I can give.

Comment: Please provide the entire command. Code code is just a single JSON, but no command. Note, `$dataAdd` is a Aggregation Pipeline Operator, you cannot use it in `insertOne` or similar.

Comment: I can't give any more information on that. As the title suggests, I'm using MongoDB Compass to insert the document. This is all the code.

Comment: "I try to insert a new document" ... using what in `Compass`? Is `"$currentDate"` a field in the document?  Is the code you show in a Compass aggregation `"$addFields"` or `"$set"` stage?